# how to change wireless network when start robot with reboot machine?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to change wireless network dynamically.I use `robot_upstart` package to automatically start the robot launch file when reboot machine. Before I want to change wireless network with command line`nmcli device wifi connect <SSID> password <PASSWORD>` everything is good.I have tried subprocess,envoy and os.system in my python scripts,they are work well with `roslaunch`,but they are all not work with the service generated by robot_upstart.But I have tried manually write the scripts into service file,it can change wireless network.Is there something wrong with `nmcli` and `robot_upstart`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280890/how-to-change-wireless-network-when-start-robot-with-reboot-machine?/) by [dyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29703/dyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, those things somehow have to do with the permissions.

To [quote the docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/robot_upstart/html/install.html#permissions):

> It’s important to understand how
> permissions work robot_upstart:

> 1.The upstart job invokes its jobname-start bash script as root.

> 2.The script sets up environment variables, and then uses setuidgid to
> execute roslaunch as an unprivileged
> user. This is by default the user who
> ran the install script, but it can
> also be specified explicitly via a
> flag.

> 3.The roslaunch which executes does not have its user’s group memberships.
> This means that it will not have
> access to serial ports with the
> dialout group, or locations in
> /var/log owned by root, etc. Any
> filesystem resources needed by your
> ROS nodes should be chowned to the
> same unprivileged user which will run
> ROS, or should set to world
> readable/writeable, for example using
> udev.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0